# Reuse Rails partials in Angular scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement Ajax functionality. I'm using Angular and I'd like to reuse a lot of Rails partials -- like forms -- that I already have. But from what I've learned from my research, Rails' `render` method cannot be accessed inside JavaScript housed in the asset pipeline.

What I have in mind is, after some event is fired -- onsubmit, onclick, etc -- replace a selected element's innerHTML with an appropriate partial.

Other answers I've seen involve using `*.js.erb` files as views but this approach doesn't appear to scale nicely -- the more Ajax calls that I have, the more controller methods and routes I'll have to set up and that sounds like the beginning of a nightmare.

So does this mean that the only way forward is to duplicate the Rails partials into Angular templates which I can then use with my JavaScript or what other options do I have?

What I'm looking for is not code, just a high level conceptual overview on how I can patch up things.

Please advise.

Comment: Typically you would convert them into Angular templates. Mixing rails ujs with angular templates is possible as you realized, but somewhat messy

Comment: I don't understand. Convert them into Angular templates such that there's those and the Rails' partials both? Or convert them into Angular templates such that I have only the Angular templates and no Rails' partials?

Answer (score 3):

When I first started working with Angular and Rails, I tried to take the approach that you're trying right now. Unfortunately, this never produced acceptable results. The problem - Angular must always know what's going on with your data. When you render erb partials via AJAX, Angular and Rails do not communicate predictably and it can be very hard to debug. Here are the high level options I would recommend:

**1. Use Rails Strictly as an API**

This approach is how most Rails/Angular apps are built. Forget about any frontend views or controllers in rails. Just build a backend API to handle requests and serve JSON data. Angular handles everything on the frontend, including routes via ngResource. Instead of Rails partials, use Angular templates. The [angular-rails-template](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) gem is helpful for getting your templates in the asset pipeline. The nice thing about this approach is that you have a pure API that can scale to other frontends, like a native iOS app. You'll also see a server-side performance boost.

**2. Mix Angular and Rails, but forget AJAX**

If you must mix erb views with Angular, avoid using `remote: true` or ajax rendering. Angular still works great for form validations and single page stuff. Turbolinks gets a bad rap in the rails community, but it actually works well in this situation.  The asynchronous page loading feels like a JS frontend, while allowing angular to compile after page load. Not ideal, but possible.

Shopify skipped Angular and built an impressive interface as with a fork of Turbolinks (turbograft), and many of its features are expected in Rails 5. [Check out this post](https://www.shopify.com/technology/15646068-rebuilding-the-shopify-admin-improving-developer-productivity-by-deleting-28-000-lines-of-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

#### routes:

```
get '/templates/*template' => 'templates#show'
```

#### api controller:

```
class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  def show
    if lookup_context.exists?("templates/#{params[:template]}")
      render(template: "templates/#{params[:template]}")
    else
      head :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

And then have angular hit that endpoint to fetch the templates you are interested in.

Comment: This looks interesting. It's the first time I'm seeing this approach so I'm wondering, is this how **you** do it or it's an approach used by **almost everyone** who's trying to tie up Angular with Rails?

Comment: Angular should be used in a way that is totally agnostic of the backend, so if you have a backend with templates, this would be the way to do it.  The front end makes an api call to get the resource it needs (in this case, some html markup).

Comment: While not quite what I was looking for, I somewhat like the concept. Upvoted.